# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$comment_count Filename: blog/index.php Line Number: 35

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My line number 35 of view/blog/index.php is as:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'post/'.$post->entry_id.'#comments';?>" class="comments">Comments (<?php echo $post->comment_count;?>)</a>
```

I have made a column in table comment as `comment_id` still its not working

and in my `model/blog_model.php` it is a function as:

```
$count = array(
        'comment_count' => $total_count,
    );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: array can't be used as object. either use $comment_count or if it is in array $post['comment_count']. Just do print_r($post) and see the result

Comment: I am thinking some where in model or code you use `result()` try with `result_array()` Not much code to go by though

Comment: Abdulla  sir, Sundar & wolfgang1983, the whole function is like this in controller/blog_model:

Comment: I am using result() but in my other functions , not in this

Comment: i have edited my post. please checkout the whole function for that particular from my controller/blog_model.php

Comment: @RaushanRanjanDas put the `$count = array(
        'comment_count' => 6,
    );` in blog controller and `$this->load->view('blog/index', $count);`

Comment: @RajeevRanjan sir, can you make it a bit more clear. I put that $count = array( 'comment_count' => 6, ); in blog controller. Now what next.?

Comment: we set data in controller for view you referenced it is model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up your notations. Question isnt very clear but if you have set an array index like...

```
$count = array(
    'comment_count' => $total_count,
);
```

And I assume passing `$count` as `$post` into your view and trying to access like this...

```
$post->comment_count
```

It wont work as this is not array notation. Correct would be..

```
$post['comment_count']
```

If `$post` and `$count` are different objects then you need to do..

```
$count['comment_count']
```

Comment: When i tried changing $post->comment_count as $post['comment_count'] it was giving an error like Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myblog\application\views\blog\index.php on line 39                                and when i tried $count['comment_count'] the previous error came which was at first.                    And yeah you are very true that i was mixing up my notations, have made some edit, hope it will make you understand my problem clearly...  Thanks and do help please

Comment: That parse error is due to your strings not being started and ended properly. Something to do with mixing up `"` and `'` probably. I expect if you resolve this then your `$post['comment_count']` will work fine

Comment: tried mixing ' and " it didn't worked and now in $post['comment_count] it is giving error like :                                                                                       Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myblog\application\views\blog\index.php on line 39    the line is same as the previous one containing $post['comment_count']

Comment: Actually it seems like it did work as the parse error is no longer showing. This error is very clear. $post is not an array it is an object and judging by the stuff above that object does not contain a property called 'comment_count'. Do `var_dump($post)` and show results in your question dont post it into some unreadable mess in a comment

Comment: u mean like that??  var_dump($post['comment_count'])

Comment: No i mean like I quoted above `var_dump($post)`

Comment: wooh! Thank you so much man! Really appreciable. Was stuck in this since morning...kudos to you for that

Comment: done. i am new here so unaware about these things! don't mind..thanks once again